# What does "/./" mean in href link?

Tags: php, html, url, path, href

Recently I'm reading some webpages and I found there are a lot of usages like:
`href="/./foo/bar.php"`

Isn't this the same as `href="/foo/bar.php"`? Or is this there something I don't know about the differences between the two ways?

Comment: Could you give an example of some page where you found this ?

Comment: Yes, this is the same. A URI basically works identical to a directory tree. These kind of constructs should be avoided and show a sloppy web app psorgramming.

Comment: This was likely done by someone that did not understand how to do directory navigation or an editor that had bad rules...  As you likely already know  `./` is the current directory and `../` is the previous directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relative URL `/./foo/bar.php` is not the same as the relative URL `/foo/bar.php`. The former has `/.` at the beginning.

They have the same effect, though. When URLs are processed, relative URLs are resolved to absolute URLs, and in this process, if a relative URL starts with `/./`, it is replaced by `/`. Reference: STD 66, clause [Remove Dot Segments](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-5.2.4). (Such a reference is turn resolved as relative to the server root, basically something like `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php`.)

So these two relative URLs *always* resolve to the same absolute URL. There is in general no reason to use the longer URL, which looks more complicated and confusing.

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with folders or files. It is simply string manipulation, based on the URL standard. Whether URLs get mapped to folders and files is at the discretion of a server and in principle invisible to the world outside it.